# using regex "\.php$" requires PCRE library in nginx.conf

Tags: php, centos, nginx, pcre

I noticed while make install nginx, it told me PCRE is not available.

I installed PCRE: yum install -y pcre

> When I restarted nginx, it shows this error:
>
> using regex ".php$" requires PCRE library in nginx.conf

I want to enable PHP-FPM. What should I do?

I am using CentOS.

Comment: Did you try to install the nginx-provided RPM from http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/i386/RPMS/?  That should be better than compiling it yourself, unless you have very particular requirements.  You can also enable the nginx repo by following the instructions from http://nginx.org/en/download.html. Once that's done, you'll have nginx under yum.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to re run configure and then make nginx again after installing pcre.